# PCR in different cell line

Tags: dna, pcr

I developed a PCR cycle to amplify a 5.5 kb genomic DNA region in HEK cell line. When I tried to use the same protocol in A375 cell line I had no results but only smear. Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running a housekeeping gene? how does that look like?

Comment: No, it's an intron of a gene upregulated in this cell line

Comment: And in this intron there is an enhancer region

Comment: Do you have a positive control run with your sample?

Comment: I use HEK gDNA as positive control

Comment: @Annalaura Your positive control should be some region that would be amplified in both samples. A test of whether the gDNA prep is good.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Yes, i have amplified 2 smaller amplicon using this gDna sample